Stop and resume process by semaphore
I wish to implement an API that utilize asyncio events in order to stop/resume a asyncio task. The API will support the following methods:

/import (start)
/stop
/resume

Main problem is happening when invoking the method /stop:
File "/src/srv.py", line 131, in __stop
    loop.run_until_complete(self.__proc.stop())
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py:-1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Application.stop' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

I've tried use await in run_until_complete, but have output:
start
# here i call /stop
end
start_stop
end_stop

i expecting this output
start
# here i call /stop
start_stop
# here i call /resume
end

I've used the following code:
srv.py
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from app import Application

class Service:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__app = FastAPI(title='api')
        self.__router = APIRouter()
        self.__router.add_api_route('/import', self.__import, methods=['POST'])
        self.__router.add_api_route('/stop', self.__stop, methods=['POST', 'GET'])
        self.__router.add_api_route('/resume', self.__resume, methods=['POST', 'GET'])
        self.__app.include_router(self.__router)
        self.__proc = Application()

    async def __import(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.__proc.import_data())

    async def __stop(self) -> None:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.__proc.stop())

    async def __resume(self) -> None:
        self.__proc.resume()

    def run(self) -> None:
        run(app=self.__app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Service().run()

app.py
import asyncio


class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__state = True
        self.__semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(1)

    async def import_data(self):
        while True:
            async with self.__semaphore:
                print('start')
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                print('end')

    def resume(self):
        self.__state = True

    async def stop(self):
        self.__state = False
        while not self.__state:
            async with self.__semaphore:
                print('start_stop')
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                print('end_stop')


The error is happening because run_until_completeis being invoked while the event loop is already running. Uvicorn already manage the eventloop for you.
Instead trying to handle the loop manually, you can use wait in the stop function to pause the task:
srv.py
async def __stop(self) -> None:
    await self.__proc.stop()

async def __import(self):
    asyncio.create_task(self.__proc.import_data())

app.py
async def import_data(self):
    while self._running:
        if not self._paused:
            print('start')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            print('end')
        else:
            # https://superfastpython.com/thread-busy-waiting-in-python/Sleep 
            # briefly while paused to avoid busy waiting
            await asyncio.sleep(1) 

def resume(self):
    self._paused = False

async def stop(self):
    self._paused = True

This avoids block event loop and enable the api to pause and resume.

when is it executed print('start') and i make request /stop, firstly he print('end'), then he stop, i want to stop him until executed print('end'), and after /resume he continue work and print('end'), cause in function import will be a lot of code

Have you tried the change I suggested? What was the behavior?

i tried, like i said, firstly he finish loop 'while self.__running:', and then he stop, but i want to stop loop in the middle
